# My NotFound Page don't appear when I deploy my project on vercel?

Tags: reactjs, json, deployment, vercel

I creat a notFound/404 Page and everything is right in my localhost but when i deploy the he show me i error place 404 page.

And I search on internet and i found this code, but when i write it in a new file called vercel.json in my code nothing happen:

this the code that i found:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)", 
      "destination": "./src/pages/NotFound/NotFound.jsx"
    }
  ]
}
```

there is any solution for this issue??

I also try this

```
{
  "routes": [
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    { "src": "/(.*)", "status": 404, "dest": "./src/pages/NotFound/NotFound.jsx" }
  ]
}
```

Nothing happen!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer is so simple I just remove what i add, from this:

```
"destination": "./src/pages/NotFound/NotFound.jsx"
```

to This

```
"destination": "/"
```

I thought that must add the path to my 404 page but i should Leave the code as it is.